# How to get dynamically the properties from a object T from a dynamically objectset<t> using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I'm trying to create a report screen that adjust itself dynamically to the contents of a database view that is present in a model generated with entity framework.

To get the entity i'm using this code:

```
var view = context.GetType().GetProperty(viewName).GetValue(context, null);
```

This code returns the `ObjectSet<viewType>` that fulfill part of my needs.

Now I need to get the properties of the view type so I can get the columns.

I tryed to used something like that:

```
var methodInfo = view .GetType().GetMethod("First");
var properties = methodInfo.ReturnType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But its not finding the method "First" and I don't know exactly where to find some help of how can I make this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get a method `first()` of `ObjectSet<viewType>` when you really want `viewType`, I believe. So this is what you need.

```
var methodInfo = view.GetType().GetGenerericArguments()[0].GetMethod("First");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First is an extension method on System.Linq.Queryable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gtype = view.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

If view is ObjectSet<FooBars>

gtype will be FooBars

Then you can call GetProperties on gtype.